# How can I combine CPU & GPU Graphics for better performance?

Tags: cpu, gpu

Can I "combine" the power of my GPU with my CPU to get more FPS in games and more power for programs ?

- CPU: Intel i5 4690K which is OC'd to 4.3Ghz with the box cooler
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7750 Saphire 1GB GDDR5 Edition which is OC'd with memory at 1130Mhz and GPU at 820Mhz, these frequencies are achieved while gaming.
- My MOBO is an Asus Z97-K
- The CPU has integrated graphics.

Comment: I wanted to suggest Lucid Vitru MVP, but sadly, it's discontinued. It also does not support Windows 10.

Comment: @DragonLord Regarding Virtu... This guy has actually tested it and he was disappointed. Even where Virtu worked, it was never _better_ than the standalone GPU http://extreme.pcgameshardware.de/grafikkarten/322151-virtu-mvp-2-0-vs-dgpu-vs-igpu.html

Comment: Was Virtu supposed to improve performance? I though it was just supposed to save power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your computer is already combining and delegating work as much as it can. The computational models, engine calculations etc. are performed by your CPU, while the GPU renders the scenes and calls the DirectX APIs.

The GPU is highly optimized for it's task and frankly it doesn't need no help from the CPU. Even if something like you are suggesting would be possible and the GPU would access the CPU's RAM, that would limit extremely the rendering for the GPU and would be of no avail. Something similar happened earlier this year with Nvidia's GTX960 which was advertised as a 4GB card, but instead had only 3.5GB with the option of accessing 500MB from the systems RAM. When this rare scenario happened, the whole perfomance collapsed.

Regarding your integrated Intel HD Graphic... I don't think it's even thinkable of running one application on two completely different GPU architectures. The application would need to be programmed so loosely coupled and asynchronously because each GPU would be waiting on the other's result, there would be no performance gain. I mean, if you just think how many compatibility limitations the manufacturers set on SLI or Crossfire, that already shows the point.

Interesting thought though.

- The only thing I would suggest to you is upgrade your HD7750 and go get an R9 290X for 200$.
- Obviously, if you can upgrade to a current-gen Nvidia card, that would be much better. (Physics run on Nvidia GPU's instead of the CPU and lately they are mopping the floor with AMD)
- Also, if you are still on a mechanical Harddrive, go get an SSD. Single most useful upgrade for ANY PC.

Comment: For now my curent radeon îs good enough for me. And I don't have money anyway for another upgrade. I already spent 450$ on my new CPU and MOBO

Comment: @TermoZour I think you invested your money in the wrong components. Should have gone for a better GPU/SSD.

Comment: Actually I wanted a better CPU for rendering and such. The procesor I had before was from 2010 and the GPU I bought in 2013 for games. But now I'm doing more rendering and with a CPU from 2010 I couldn't do anything. That's why I now have a better CPU than GPU. I could get a new GPU too but I didn't need one yet.

Comment: @TermoZour sorry, from the question i thought youe were pushing for better gaming perfomance.

Comment: NO problem. As in gaming, I can already do pretty much what I want, and having my GPU and VRAM OC-d at MAX is an advantage. The only thing I care now is rendering and VERY DEMANDING programs. That's where I need horse power ;)

Comment: As of DDR4 this answer is no longer relevant or correct. Windows 10 now has "shared memory" as both GPU memory and system memory. This allows the use of GPU memory in non-graphical tasks by the CPU and system memory as extra GPU memory.